# Update table and enumerate rows depends to another column

Tags: mysql

I have a simple table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `test1` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cat_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `price` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `rank` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Let's say it contains list of products, each product have category ID and the price. I want to update the table and fill `rank` column and give each product a rank depends on its price (from higher to lower), but rank should depends on the category. In other words each category should have its #1 product which is the most expensive in that category. I would like to do it with a single query (if it's possible).

I know how to rank all products without dependency on category

```sql
UPDATE `test1` 
SET `rank`=(SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 rank_num FROM (SELECT @rank:=0) r) 
ORDER BY `cat_id` ASC, `price` DESC
```

But how to add a dependency on category ID?

Comment: Use RANK() or DENSE_RANK() with suitable window definition.

Comment: @Akina `RANK` function can't be used in UPDATE, if you try you will get an error "Window function is allowed only in SELECT list and ORDER BY clause"

Comment: Of course, the subquery which uses another table copy needed. This is true not for RANK() only but for any selection from the table to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone looking for the answer for such question, I have found a solution. Thanks to @Akina to point the right direction.

```sql
UPDATE test1 as t,
    (SELECT *, RANK() OVER (
            PARTITION BY cat_id  ORDER BY price DESC
        ) row_rank
    FROM test1) as r
SET t.rank=r.row_rank
WHERE t.id=r.id
```